# Add tagname & classname in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using using Marionette for my single page application. I'm using require.js & handlebar in that application. So in each view I'm requiring the external template and adding that as template within the view:-

```
define([
//libs
'marionette', "backbone", "jquery", "handlebar",

// view templates
'text!templates/home.html'],

function(Marionette, Backbone, $, HandleBars, homeTpl) {

    return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        className : 'home',
        tagName : 'div',
        template : HandleBars.compile( homeTpl )

    });
});
```

The template for the home view is:-

```
  <div class="home">
          <span> Home </span>
  </div>
```

And I've added 'home' as className, so I modified the home template to to remove extra div:-

```
   <span> Home </span>
```

Now, in another view the template is:-

```
    <div class="logo">
          <span> logo </span>
    </div>
     <div class="about">
          <span> about </span>
    </div>
```

So, how I can add className for the view? I don't want to add extra divs in the dom.

Comment: So whats problem ? same way like in prev view... btw,there is no need to define `div` as `tagName` its default

Comment: In the second case, there is no parent class to be added in the view, the logo and the about class are siblings.

Comment: decompose your view in 2 (LogoView and AboutView) - logic will be same like in first case

Comment: Yeah, that's a good option. But thing is that, suppose the logo div just the logo, just a static html, so is it good practice to create a new view for this static html? I mean whether creating multiple without any dynamic data is a good option? Besides I'm showing the view in a region, how can I show two view in a region using region.show() method? Should I use layout there?

Comment: If its static maybe you can keep it startup HTML page ? I cant say it bad practice, but if you take a look on logo view a bit wider - it may be instance of ImageView or LinkedImageView and may be usefull for other project pages. You can use LayoutView to divide region in two or just update HTML page you start with with one region more on app level

Comment: Though the content of the view is static, I can't add it in the start up html. Because that view will come depending on the route. But I can divide the view in multiple views and then layout to show it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65951/discussion-between-evgeniy-and-indra).